# Error while creating rails Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to start a rails projec, when I try to create the database with "rake db:create" y recive the following:

`postgresql_adapter.rb:898:in 'rescue in connect': FATAL:  database "Real_Estate_development" does not exist`
`Run '$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate' to create your database (ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError)`

My database.yml contains:

`development: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: Real_Estate_development
  username: "ruby"
  password: "ruby123"
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  min_messages: warning
  pool: 2
  timeout: 5000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `psql -U ruby -d postgres -W ruby123` to confirm the user have access right.

Maybe `$ bin/rake db:create` solve the problem as the error message suggests.